# Crop Image C# Without Background

Tags: c#, image

I am trying to crop an image with C# but i have some problem.

I need to crop this image and remove 15 pixels from top:[image]

I have used this code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(outputFileName);
Rectangle destRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 15), new Size(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height));
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0, destRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
bmp.Save(outputFileNameCut, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

outputFileName is the path of the first image and outputFileNameCut the path for the new image. It works fine but when i save the image, the image saved is so:

[image]

It seems that also the quality is less. Both the images are .jpg

Thank you

Comment: Don't use JPG for images like this. PNG is lossless and perfect for something like a barcode. That said, you're not cropping - you're rescaling. You also need to use the source rectangle to crop the image.

Comment: When you say 'crop', do you mean 'remove the white space on the left and right'? Also, it looks like you're not addressing the change in height in your resultant rectangle. Shouldn't that be myBitmap.Height - 15?

Comment: I have used png but i always have a lossless quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(outputFileName);
Rectangle destRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 15), 
new Size(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height));
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height - 15);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0, destRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
bmp.Save(outputFileNameCut, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

*On a side note, this may make the bar code invalid to use. Because you are modifying and resizing the image, which may interfere with some scanners to some degree.*